# Creating a String in Python 3 using indexing

Tags: python, string

I need to create a string that returns the characters from the column of the board with index column_index as a single string.

I need to return the below

```
>>> make_str_from_column([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 1)
'NS
```

I had initially done

```
def makedef make_str_from_column(board, column_index):
    """ (list of list of str, int) -> str """
    if column_index >=0:
        return board[0][column_index] +board[1][column_index]
```

however, I cannot use the 0 and 1 these are really just hardcoded to get me to the answer I want

I am a bit lost on how to replace the 0 and 1

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please edit your question to format the code samples as code. Highlight it and click on the { } button

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
def makedef make_str_from_column(board, column_index): 
  if len(board) == 0:
    return ''
  if column_index >=0 and column_index < len(board[0]): 
    return ''.join([board[i][column_index] for i in range(len(board))])
```

Comment: do I really need the first if statement?

Comment: That is because I am doing len(board[0]) in the next if statement

Comment: can you explain to me what the len(board[0]) is doing?  is that showing that there are 4 columns?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming all lengths inside the board (board[0], board[1], etc) are equal and then checking if column_index < len(board[0]) because otherwise it will throw an error

Comment: the i , how does python view the i?  I think that is where I am getting caught up

Comment: I am running a loop for `for i in range(len(board))` so i will start from 0 and go to len(board) - 1, in your case since len(board) is 2, i will be 0 then 1